# how to escape slash in jQuery

Tags: jquery, string, escaping

i am using mathjax for mathematical rendering.

i can't pass latex syntax through jQuery html() function.

is there any way to escape slash in jQuery.

Latex Syntax : `\(\begin{equation}\hat{y}\end{equation}\)`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/QVB4Q/)

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/QVB4Q/3/

Comment: If so, you just need to use double back slashes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use another Slash:

```
\\(\\begin{equation}\\hat{y}\\end{equation}\\)
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QVB4Q/2/)

Answer (score 0):

the slash stands for: the character coming after me is a special character, like \n, \t etc. etc. 
If you want to use some characters that is already in use by the language just like " or \ you can also use a slash before them \" \ and so